# How to stop two visitors hitting a PHP script at the same second

Tags: php, function, sleep

Hi I have had an issue where two visitors have hit a php function within a second of each other. This function sends them a one time use code from a pool of codes and it sent both people the same code.

What methods can I use in my script to check if someone else is already being processed and either delay or wait for the other person to finish?

I know this seems a really general question its hard to explain what I mean! Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Don't block requests.... just make sure that the pool can't send the same code twice..... of course, you haven't said anything about how your pool works, so it's difficult for us to advise you in any more detail

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 1):

> What methods can I use in my script to check if someone else is already being processed and either delay or wait for the other person to finish?

That would be what we call a "mutex", short for *mutually exclusive*.

Notice that without knowing how your PHP is run on your server, it's hard to know whether PHP's built-in [mutex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mutex.php) routines will work. PHP is a bad language when it comes to multithreading.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mutex.php in English please ;-) and not http://php.net/manual/de/class.mutex.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- ooops; sorry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If your pool of codes lives in the database you could use transactions and lock tables for reading when one of the requests is trying to obtain the code. Wherever the data are, you will have to introduce some way locking or queuing requests to deal with concurrent requests.